# SSRS Report - Complex Layout?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a report, but I'm unsure how to get the layout correct.

The way the report should look is [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjv2v.jpg)

The data is currently formatted like so:

```
Customer No | Sale Price | Cost Price | Margin | Date
Customer A  |   200      |    100     |  100   |  1/1/14
```

Is it possible to design a report with this layout? I suspect so, but I haven't encountered this issue yet.

Any hints and tips to get me on my way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. My tip to get you on your way: Just start doing it and come back when you encounter problems. Hint: The clue is to select the data the right way - designing the report is easy then.

Answer (score 3):

Since what you want is actually a cross-tab, it is easier if your dataset is structured like this:

```
Customer No   Price Type   Date     Amount
-----------   ----------   -------  ------
Customer A    Sale         1/1/14   200
Customer A    Cost         1/1/14   100
Customer A    Margin       1/1/14   100
...
```

To achieve this, simply use UNION ALL in the SQL statement of your dataset, like so:

```
SELECT [Customer No], 'Sale' AS [Price Type], [Date], [Sale Price]
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [Customer No], 'Cost' AS [Price Type], [Date], [Cost Price]
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [Customer No], 'Margin' AS [Price Type], [Date], [Margin]
FROM MyTable
```

With a dataset like this, it is straightforward to get the report layout you want, for example using the Tablix Wizard.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've bookmarked it for next time I come across something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. It actually wasn't too difficult, to my surprise. This probably isn't the best way to do things, but it worked well for me!

**Query**

```
SELECT sa.[Document No_]
    ,[sa.Customer No_]
    ,DATEPART(m, sa.[Posting Date]) AS MonthName
    ,sa.Quantity
    ,sa.[Amount (LCY)]
    ,sa.[Cost (LCY)]
    ,sa.[Profit  (LCY)]
    ,c.[Salesperson Code]
    ,c.NAME
FROM [Sales Analysis] AS sa
INNER JOIN [Customer] AS c ON c.[No_] = sa.[customer no_]
WHERE [Posting Date] BETWEEN '2014-01-01'   AND '2014-05-31'
    AND [Customer No_] IS NOT NULL
    AND [Customer No_] <> ''
```

**Matrix Layout**
[image: http://i.imgur.com/vSDYBzC.jpg]

**Results**
[image]
Thanks for the help!